# Shopee OpenAPI 1.0 Authorization and Authentication always return “No partner_id”

Tags: rest, authorization, http-post

I am following the OpenAPI 1.0 authorization guide here (https://open.shopee.com/documents?module=63&type=2&id=53). I did the shop authorization and it successfully returning the code and shop_ID in the redirect URL.

Next I was trying the API request authentication to get shop info. The signature base string I created was this:

```
https://partner.uat.shopeemobile.com/api/v1/shop/get|{"partner_id": XXXXXX, "shopid": XXXXXXXXX, "timestamp": XXXXXXXXXX}
```

I combined this signature base string with the test key that I got from creating an app to produce the hex output. This output is placed on the Authorization header in my POST request along with these parameters in the body: partner_id, shopid, and timestamp. The result I got was always this:

```
{"request_id":"595b9b4bdb0b056392f8a44834dd06e7","msg":"partner_id is invalid, should be an integer between 0 and 4294967295","error":"error_param"}
```

I also tried this POST request without any header, but the result is always the same. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In this error you should be use `partner_id` of `integer`, not `string`.